# Flutter - Font not rendering properly

Tags: android, flutter, fonts

I am using a font that should look like this:
[image]

But, instead, it's been rendered like this:
[image]

To make things more complicated, it is not wrong in every device. Only some android devices are experiencing this issue.

Somebody here had the same problem?

I've tried to emulate the problem using the same device that the user is using in Browserstack, but I can't replicate the problem.

Comment: looks to be a fontWeight issue, try setting a lighter weight

Comment: @CStark, that font family only has one fontWeight (regular). :/

Comment: @dap.tci It can be a theme-related issue. Are you using a custom theme based on any default theme? Try defining more related values in your theme.

Comment: honestly this looks like a rendering issue that could be worth bringing up to the flutter team by creating a new bug on the [flutter github](https://github.com/flutter/flutter). It would also be interesting to see what happens if you build using the `flutter run --enable-impeller` flag, although that isn't really ready for production yet.

Comment: Also might be worth trying to convert the font to a different format (i.e. otf instead of ttf) to see if it works after conversion; there might be a rounding or decimal issue that the renderer is handling incorrectly for that format.